# Request doesn't work when I use filter() in collection Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

I am trying to get a filter in a collection, but I get an error:

> "code": 500,
>       "error_msg": "Undefined variable: request"

This is my code where I have the error. The request works in any part of the code, but not here...

```
   $filterKarateka = $karatekasInMarket ->filter(function($item) {           
      return $item->id == $request->id_karateka; 
                    })->first();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to `use`  as in include variables that are out of scope of the callback. So it would be

```
filter(function ($item) use ($request){
```